# I'm getting confused with Gaussian Process Prior sampling

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I'm having a hard time understanding Gaussian Processes prior sampling. Here is the article from medium I'm using to learn about Gaussian Processes [Article link](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-gaussian-process-the-socratic-way-ba02369d804).

I'm going to start off by explaining my understanding of the partconfuses me. So we get the probability of 2 functions using this PDF equation. I'll call it equation_1
[image]
[image]

Then we plot each function and get the probability of each function using this pdf graph. I'll call it graph_1 because I'm going to ask questions abput it later on
[image]

After it is assumed that the prior is sampled using 600 data points and 50 functions are obtained. I've put the graph obtained below. I'll call it graph_2

[image]

P.S: If you don't understand my questions because I missed out a few details, you can refer to thsi Article for missing details. [Article link](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-gaussian-process-the-socratic-way-ba02369d804)
**My Questions**

1. When training the GP prior, is X and X* two data points from the raining data?
2. For graph_1, where does the Gaussian distribution come from?, also where do the positions of the functions on the x-axis come from? are they the standard deviation postions of the functions results?
3. For graph_2, whats on the y axis? Is it the results axis standardised i.e instead of showing the actual result, the standardised result is shown?